# Using NSShadow on Navigation Bar Button Items in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, nsshadow

I have a navigation bar that looks like so:

[image]

It was created with the following code:

```
//  AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    NSShadow *textShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    textShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 5.0;
    textShadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.0 alpha: 0.75];
    textShadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{ NSShadowAttributeName: textShadow } forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    return YES;
}
```

**Questions**

1. Where is the shadowBlurRadius (at least for the "Edit" button)? Notice that I set `textShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 5.0;`. Cranking up that value doesn't seem to do anything either.
2. Is it possible to add a shadow to the "+" bar button item or other bar button items that are not text (e.g. UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera)? I'd like to avoid generating my own rasterized images.

**This question pertains to iOS 7 only.**

Comment: Have you ever fixed this? I've just hit the same problem. I can't seem to make `shadowBlurRadius` do anything...

Answer (score 1):

Actually your shadow is getting rendered on `UIBarButonItem` & you can see the white shadow in the "Edit" bar button item text. If you want to use better shadow appearance then please try to play with values in `CGSizeMake` here within range of -1, 1, 0

```
textShadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0);
```

A bit tricky, but to add shadow to the right bar button item, please make a `UIBarButton` with title on it as `+` &  assign it to the `rightBarButton` of navigation Item & you will get the shadow affect as you see in the left bar button item.

Hopw that helps.

Comment: Balram, thanks for taking the time to answer my questions. That said, the first question was not about the shadow being rendered on the "Edit" button. I'm not blind ;) The question is about not seeing the shadowBlurRadius. Modifying the offset is not going to help with that. The "+" character isn't really relevant to #2 either, as I might ask the same question of a different button style that isn't text (e.g. UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera).

Comment: Also not seeing the shadowBlurRadius do anything at all.